# Excel macro to group rows based on a cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have a hierarchical list of items in an Excel worksheet and want to create a macro to group each row based on a cell value that gives the level of indention. The data looks like this:

```
Index  Level  Name
1      1      Assembly 1
2      2      Sub-assembly 1
3      2      Sub-assembly 2
3      3      Sub-sub-assembly 1
3      3      Sub-sub-assembly 2
4      2      Sub-assembly 3
```

After the macro runs, the level 2 rows would be grouped one level (i.e. the equivalent of selecting the row and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>, and the level 3 rows would be grouped two levels.

Comment: Howdy! We're not a macro-writing service.  What have you got so far? Where exactly are you getting stuck implementing your macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub AutoGroupBOM()
    'Define Variables
    Dim StartCell As Range 'This defines the highest level of assembly, usually 1, and must be the top leftmost cell of concern for outlining, its our starting point for grouping'
    Dim StartRow As Integer 'This defines the starting row to beging grouping, based on the row we define from StartCell'
    Dim LevelCol As Integer 'This is the column that defines the assembly level we're basing our grouping on'
    Dim LastRow As Integer 'This is the last row in the sheet that contains information we're grouping'
    Dim CurrentLevel As Integer 'iterative counter'
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turns off screen updating while running.

    'Prompts user to select the starting row. It MUST be the highest level of assembly and also the top left cell of the range you want to group/outline"
    Set StartCell = Application.InputBox("Select top left cell for highest assembly level", Type:=8)
    StartRow = StartCell.Row
    LevelCol = StartCell.Column
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'Remove any pre-existing outlining on worksheet, or you're gonna have 99 problems and an outline ain't 1
    Cells.ClearOutline

    'Walk down the bom lines and group items until you reach the end of populated cells in the assembly level column
    For i = StartRow To LastRow
        CurrentLevel = Cells(i, LevelCol)
        Rows(i).Select
        For j = 1 To CurrentLevel - 1
            Selection.Rows.Group
        Next j
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turns on screen updating when done.

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a macro to group rows based on an index like that:

1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3

To do that, I used your macro and changed it a little:

```
Sub AutoGroupBOM(control As IRibbonControl)
    'Define Variables
    Dim StartCell As Range 'This defines the highest level of assembly, usually 1, and must be the top leftmost cell of concern for outlining, its our starting point for grouping'
    Dim StartRow As Integer 'This defines the starting row to beging grouping, based on the row we define from StartCell'
    Dim LevelCol As Integer 'This is the column that defines the assembly level we're basing our grouping on'
    Dim LastRow As Integer 'This is the last row in the sheet that contains information we're grouping'
    Dim CurrentLevel As Integer 'iterative counter'
    Dim groupBegin, groupEnd As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turns off screen updating while running.

    'Prompts user to select the starting row. It MUST be the highest level of assembly and also the top left cell of the range you want to group/outline"
    Set StartCell = Application.InputBox("Select levels' column top cell", Type:=8)
    StartRow = StartCell.ROW
    LevelCol = StartCell.Column
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.End(xlDown).ROW 'empty rows above aren't included in UsedRange.rows.count => UsedRange.End

    'Remove any pre-existing outlining on worksheet, or you're gonna have 99 problems and an outline ain't 1
    Cells.ClearOutline

    'Walk down the bom lines and group items until you reach the end of populated cells in the assembly level column
    groupBegin = StartRow + 1 'For the first group
    For i = StartRow + 1 To LastRow
        CurrentLevel = Cells(i, LevelCol)

        If Cells(i, LevelCol).Value <> Cells(i - 1, LevelCol).Value Then
            groupEnd = i - 1
            Rows(groupBegin & ":" & groupEnd).Select
            'If is here to prevent grouping level that have only one row
            If Cells(groupBegin - 1, LevelCol).Value = Cells(groupBegin, LevelCol).Value Then Selection.Rows.Group
            groupBegin = i + 1 'adding one to keep the group's first row
        End If

    Next i

    'For last group
    Rows(groupBegin & ":" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.Rows.Group

    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1 'Minimize all the groups
    ActiveSheet.Outline.SummaryRow = xlAbove 'Put "+" next to first line of each group instead of the bottom
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turns on screen updating when done.

End Sub
```